# Can't update Android gradle plugin version

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm trying to update Android gradle plugin from 3.5.1 to 3.6.1.

And got error:

```
Cannot cast object 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2$1@67833830' with class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask$2$1' to class 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.pipeline.TransformTask'
```

There is not this error on 3.5.1 - 3.5.3. It reproduce only on 3.6.0 - 3.6.1

- Gradle 6.2.2
- Android Studio 3.6
- Android SDK Platform-Tools 29.0.6
- compileSdkVersion 29
- targetSdkVersion 29

Comment: Whats version in `distributionUrl`?

Comment: @PratikButani distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.2.2-all.zip

Comment: Make it `5.6.4`

Comment: @PratikButani Thank you for the answer. Still doesn't work.

Comment: Please Update Android Studio to 3.6.1 and use above distributionUrl

Comment: Did you try to update the android studio?

Comment: I have the latest Android Studio

Comment: please post your dependency list or both `build.gradle` files.

Comment: I have Android Studio `3.6.1`, Distribution Gradle `5.6.5` and build-gradle `3.6.1` and i have the same error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered the same thing after updating gradle plugin from version 3.5.3 to 4.0.0. It turned out, that there was a problem with [AspectJ plugin](https://github.com/HujiangTechnology/gradle_plugin_android_aspectjx) `com.hujiang.aspectjx:gradle-android-plugin-aspectjx:2.0.5`. After updating the plugin to version 2.0.10 the problem disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

As per this documentation:

**[Gradle Version 3.6.0](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#3-6-0)**

This version of the Android plugin requires the following:

- Gradle 5.6.4. To learn more, read the section about updating Gradle.
- SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 or higher.

It's working.

Comment: Thank you for answer. According to the table in documentation (https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle), 3.6.0+ to 5.6.4+. I use the latest version 6.2.2. Anyway 5.6.4 doesn't work too.